# Regex : Get number beetween double brackets

Tags: php, regex

I need a php regex that allow to transform `{{[1][value|other]}}` to  `{{1}}`

I have tried a lot of regex but no result, it works only with the first occurence like that :

My text : `Hello {{[1][miss|mr]}} {{[2][Maria|Jon]}}`

The result I want : `Hello {{1}} {{2}}`

```
$pattern = '/{{\[(\d+)\].+}}/';
$matches = [];
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

Give me that :

```
Array

(

    [0] => {{[1][miss|mr]}} {{[2][Maria|Jon]}}

    [1] => 1

)
```

But I need also the "2"

Comment: ok thanks ! I resume the code cause I havent a "perfect" english and I thought my problem was more easy to understant like that ! sorry

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far. You mention you tried a lot of regex, but you don't show it so we can't know what you have tried and where the problems are. This is not a site to get free coding services, which is why simple "Please give me the code to my problem, I tried something and it didn't work" requests without any proof that you really *did* try something are often downvoted heavily. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: is OK - is hard to kinda ask on your first ! - but try to read the question back and see if you could answer on everything you gave :) there are other StackOverflow sites - maybe there's one for a language you find more comfortable :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie It works with one thanks ! But if I have a textarea like that : `Hello {{[1][miss|mr]}} {{[2][Maria|Jon]}}` I need to do this on each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple matter of matching/consuming the characters that you wish to remove and capture the characters that you want to keep.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GdIsZX/1/

PHP (https://3v4l.org/L5NSj)

```
$text = 'Hello {{[1][miss|mr]}} {{[2][Maria|Jon]}}';
echo preg_replace('~\[(\d+)]\[[^]]*]~', '$1', $text);
```

Output:

```
Hello {{1}} {{2}}
```

The above pattern is not designed to validate the substring.  The focus is efficient, generalized matching. If you need a more strict/accurate pattern, you will need to improve your question with input that better represents your challenge.

p.s. if you want to match the curly braces but not remove them, you can use `\K` and a lookahead.

https://3v4l.org/5oNrL

```
~{{\K\[(\d+)]\[[^]]*](?=}})~
```